# New home has 240v Nema 14-30R for Electric Dryer I have A gas dryer Needing Nema 5-15R

Tags: electrical, dryer, gas

I just purchased a 2 year old home in the laundry room on the wall for the washer & Dryer there is 1 -  120v Jack and 1 Nema 14-30R Jack.

My washer only needs 5a 120v Nema 5-15R.

Do I need to run a separate breaker and a stand alone outlet?  (GFI or arc Fault?)

Thank you "

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from converting the single 120v outlet to a dual outlet?  I'm assuming the 120v outlet is already on a dedicated circuit.

Comment: What does "*1 - 120v Jack*" mean?

Answer (score 1):

If the 120V receptacle is a simplex (single) receptacle just replace it with a duplex. You can share it with the washer. This assumes the cord from the dryer will reach.

If you are unsure of how to do this please comment back.